# How do I check with Roslyn if a Type is a Nullable Reference

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis, nullable-reference-types

I am trying to analyze with roslyn if a type declaration is a "Nullable Reference" type (C#8)

I was planing on looking if the `TypeSyntex` was a `NullableTypeSyntax` and if the `ITypeSymbol.IsReferenceType` is `true`.

The following code works for the most part, but is fails when the declared type is generic i.e. `List<T>?`

```cs
void Main()
{
    string text = @"
        #nullable enable
        public class MyClass
        {
            public string? Get() => null;
            public List<string>? GetGeneric() => null;
        }";
    SyntaxTree tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(text);
    PortableExecutableReference mscorlib = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);
    CSharpCompilation compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("RefitCompilation", syntaxTrees: new[] { tree }, references: new[] { mscorlib });
    SemanticModel semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree);

    MethodDeclarationSyntax nonGenericMethodSyntax = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>().First();
    ITypeSymbol nonGenericReturnType = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(nonGenericMethodSyntax.ReturnType).Type;
    bool isNullableTypeReference = nonGenericMethodSyntax.ReturnType is NullableTypeSyntax && nonGenericReturnType.IsReferenceType;
    Console.WriteLine($@"NonGeneric Nullalbe Reference: `{nonGenericMethodSyntax}`
        Is Nullable Type Reference: {isNullableTypeReference}
        Original Definition: {nonGenericReturnType.OriginalDefinition}, 
        IsNullableTypeSyntax: {nonGenericMethodSyntax.ReturnType is NullableTypeSyntax}
        Is Reference Type: {nonGenericReturnType.IsReferenceType}");

    Console.WriteLine();

    MethodDeclarationSyntax genericMethodSyntax = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>().Last();
    ITypeSymbol genericReturnType = semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(genericMethodSyntax.ReturnType).Type;
    isNullableTypeReference = genericMethodSyntax.ReturnType is NullableTypeSyntax && genericReturnType.IsReferenceType;
    Console.WriteLine($@"Generic Nullalbe Reference: `{genericMethodSyntax}`
        Is Nullable Type Reference: {isNullableTypeReference}
        Original Definition: {genericReturnType.OriginalDefinition}, 
        IsNullableTypeSyntax: {genericMethodSyntax.ReturnType is NullableTypeSyntax}
        Is Reference Type: {genericReturnType.IsReferenceType}");
}
```

which outputs

```
NonGeneric Nullalbe Reference: `public string? Get() => null;`
        Is Nullable Type Reference: True
        Original Definition: string, 
        IsNullableTypeSyntax: True
        Is Reference Type: True

Generic Nullalbe Reference: `public List<string>? GetGeneric() => null;`
        Is Nullable Type Reference: False
        Original Definition: System.Nullable<T>, 
        IsNullableTypeSyntax: True
        Is Reference Type: False
```

Why is `List<T>?` Original Definition `System.Nullable<T>`? and how can I determine if a type is a Nullable Reference type?

Comment: What's about `semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(nonGenericMethodSyntax.ReturnType).Nullability.Annotation`?

Comment: `semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(nonGenericMethodSyntax.ReturnType).Nullability.Annotation` is None. `Nullability.FlowState` is None as well

Comment: Is still happen? Which version of Rosalyn do you use? It works for me in the latest version (3.5.0 beta 1) - `IsReferenceType = true`

Comment: @DudiKeleti I tried it with [3.5.0 beta 1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/3.5.0-beta1-final) I still get the same output. if you have linqpad open [this](http://share.linqpad.net/r2g8oq.linq)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer but I had the same issue and this is my interpretation of things.

In

```
string text = @"
    #nullable enable
    public class MyClass
    {
        public string? Get() => null;
        public List<string>? GetGeneric() => null;
    }";
```

the `List<string>?` is invalid, the `System.Collections.Generic` using is missing, therefore it is not possible to determine the type of `List<string>`.

What happens next is that the unknown `List<T>?` type is interpreted as nullable struct so we arrive at `Nullable<List<string>>`.

This case can be checked by interrogating the `Nullable` for its underlying type and checking its `TypeKind`, i.e.

```
((INamedTypeSymbol)type).TypeArguments[0].TypeKind
```

will yield `Error`.

Answer (score 0):

symbol.type.NullableAnnotation will give whether the expression is annotated or not

[image: ENUM Desc]